# Multiple similar DocumentListeners using class properties - How to condense them to one listener?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I have a class `TestListeners`, containing some JTextFields and other properties (integers here). I want the properties to update when the corresponding JTextField text changes. Therefore, I added some DocumentListeners, but these listeners do almost exactly the same thing, just the target property is different. The goal is to have only one listener which can be added to all three JTextFields and for each JTextField the corresponding class property should be handled.

I found the following question which helped me get the JTextField dynamically into the listener without having to hardcode them in there:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25895/applying-documentlistener-on-multiple-jtextfield

But I can't find a way to dynamically reference the property, which should be changed, in the listener. I'd be glad if somebody could help to find a way.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TestListeners extends JFrame {
    Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
    Color red = new Color(255, 200, 200);
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField("11111");
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField("22222");
    JTextField field3 = new JTextField("33333");
    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    int value3 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestListeners();
    }

    public TestListeners() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx++; this.add(field1, c);
        c.gridx++; this.add(field2, c);
        c.gridx++; this.add(field3, c);

        field1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field1.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field1.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field1.getText());
            }

            private void filterText(String text) {
                try {
                    value1 = Integer.parseInt(text);
                    field1.setBackground(white);
                    System.out.println("value1 = " + value1);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    System.out.println("text in field1 is not an integer");
                    field1.setBackground(red);
                }
            }
        });

        field2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field2.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field2.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field2.getText());
            }

            private void filterText(String text) {
                try {
                    value2 = Integer.parseInt(text);
                    field2.setBackground(white);
                    System.out.println("value2 = " + value2);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    System.out.println("text in field2 is not an integer");
                    field2.setBackground(red);
                }
            }
        });

        field3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field3.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field3.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                filterText(field3.getText());
            }

            private void filterText(String text) {
                try {
                    value3 = Integer.parseInt(text);
                    field3.setBackground(white);
                    System.out.println("value3 = " + value3);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    System.out.println("text in field3 is not an integer");
                    field3.setBackground(red);
                }
            }
        });

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If "call-by-reference" existed in Java as it does in C++, this problem could be solved easily by passing a reference for `value1` etc. to the listener.

Comment: Or like you can do in JavaScript: `someObject["value1"] = 123;`

Answer (score 3):

You are using anonymous classes to implement your `DocumentListner`.

You can of course create a new class

```
public class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListner {

  public MyDocumentListener (TestListeners parentFrame) {
     // either via getter or in your example:

     parentFrame.value3 = 123; // value3 is packed protected.
  }
 // copy paste your methods here.
}
```

You will have to pass a reference to your GUI items you want to change to a new instance of `MyDocumentListener`.

Note that you have member variables without any modifier. Thus this member are packet protected. As long as your new class is in the same packed as `TestListeners` you can access them without a getter. Otherwise implement getter and setter for this values.

You can do this by implementing a proper constructor.

You can add then the `DocumentListner` like this:

```
field3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListner(this));
```

We have to pass "this" to the new instance of MyDocumentListner so new listener is able to access fields from it.

---

Or you can create an object consisting of your anonymous classes:

```
DocumentListner myListener = new DoucmentListener {
  // implement your methods here
}
```

Then you can pass the `DocumentListener` to your fields like this:

```
field3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(myListener);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. How would I inside the listener refer to `value3` of the class `TestListener`, if I add this listener to `field3` (to follow your example)?

Comment: As i wrote: You have to pass a reference to TestListener via constructor. I will update my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks you. But putting `parentFrame.value3` into the listener is just as hardcoded as I did it in the question already, because `MyDocumentListener` would only work for `value3` then and no other. I'd have to create other classes to work with `value1` and `value2` which in the end results in the same as the ultimate example with the anonymous classes, only that the classes are not anonymous anymore.

Comment: Due to your design you won't have much options. You can access the TextField via DocumentEvent e => e.getSource(). But you still won't be able to associate it to your int value without using reflection or hardcode it. Via my first given approach you can extend your Listener to do more specific stuff. Implementing similar behavior to a abstract parent Listener.

Comment: I'd be happy to change the design if that could help with this value problem, but as it seems there is now way to call-by-reference in Java.

Comment: have a look at the mvc pattern.

Comment: Well, I am using MVC in the project this problem occured in. I just simplified and condensed everything to a single class to be able to post a working example here without breaking the mold.

Answer (score 2):

Start by focusing on what is common between the listeners, they verify the state of `JTextField`, but they also maintain the last valid value.

So, you need a listener which can get the text from a `JTextField`, can change it's state, depending on the current text and which can maintain the last valid value, something like...

```
public class VerifyHandler implements DocumentListener {

    private int value;
    private JTextField field;

    public VerifyHandler(JTextField field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        filterText();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        filterText();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        filterText();
    }

    private void filterText() {
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            field.setBackground(white);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            field.setBackground(red);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, frankly, this seems like a lot of work for something that has already been implemented.

For example, you could use a `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField` or event a `DocumentFilter` to prevent the user from ever entering anything other then what you want.

See:

- [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)
- [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
- [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

for more details

Comment: May I ask something related, apart from this evaluation issue, which just came to my mind? I'm currently questioning the reasonability of updating my model everytime something changes in the view, when I actually need all the values only when the user presses a "Start" button. It would save me hundreds of lines of code if I get the values from the view and set them in the model, just when the user hits "Start". Is there an argument against that?

Comment: Nope. I'd use the view to as a intermediate container of the values, which can be used to provide the user with immediate feedback to any potential issues (ie we know the field requires a number, but not the acceptable range, for example)